# TypeException: Savepoint does not exist in this context

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, rollback, savepoint

Is there a limitation that prevents unit tests from calling a class that uses the Database.rollback functionality? I am getting this error:

> System.TypeException: Savepoint does not exist in this context

More than anything I am surprised that a Google search for the above error message is returning zero results!

Here's a code snippet. This code works perfectly fine when executed outside the test context.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static Savepoint sp;
    public static void doWork()
    {
        if (sp == null) sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        try { /* do work */ }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (sp != null) Database.rollback(sp);
        }
    }
}

trigger AccountTrigger on (before insert)
{
    MyClass.doWork();
}

@isTest
private class MyClassTest
{
    @isTest
    static void rollback()
    {
        // exception here
        insert list of 200+ Accounts
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This error only happens when the trigger is forced to execute more than once (i.e. 200+ records inserted). So clearly Apex doesn't like the `Savepoint` to remain in static memory for the entire transaction.

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of the code? It seems like `Database.setSavepoint()` has not been executed prior rollback - there is no context for the rollback. Both savepoint and rollback are mutually inclusive.

Comment: @BorisBachovski I just added my code. I have a feeling this is not going to be a trivial issue to resolve, but I was hoping the mere sight of the error message would ring the bell for someone. Otherwise I am no newcomer to Database rollbacks.

Comment: Declare the save point in the method not as a static property of the class.

Comment: @Eric that's not what I want though. I need the Savepoint to be in the static memory throughout the Apex execution session.

Comment: Does it work when not static? If so then u may not have a choice.

Comment: What Eric said. Not sure if you can have it outside the method, as a matter of fact I've never tried that...

Comment: As mentioned in the question this code works absolutely beautifully outside test context. I don't have a great memory but I believe several years ago this configuration was resulting in a runtime error. The undocumented error message is more the reason to believe this might have been a relatively recent change.

Comment: There is difference in Transaction and Context. `Savepoint` are for transaction only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on **[Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm)** clearly lays out that a `Savepoint` cannot be used across trigger invocations:

> - References to savepoints cannot cross trigger invocations because each trigger invocation is a new trigger context. If you declare a savepoint as a static variable then try to use it across trigger contexts, you will receive a run-time error.

I didn't post this link in response to your original post because you implied you were inserting exactly one record, which wouldn't cause this error. But when you insert more than 200 records, you get trigger batching.

You may also want to read up on [Apex Transactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm), which doesn't explicitly state that separate trigger invocations caused by trigger batching will be separate transactions, but will give you a better frame of reference for understanding what a transaction is.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was thrown off by the error and how it wasn't documented. My second pair of eyes (who is also a seasoned SF dev) played around on his machine and thought it might be a unit test limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out having the `Savepoint` in the static memory is fine as long as the trigger is executed once. But regardless of whether we are in test mode the TypeException is thrown when the trigger is executed twice.

Ashwani's comment helped me realize this: There is difference in Transaction and Context. `Savepoint` are for transaction only.